# vim global command matching multiple lines and merging them

Tags: regex, vim

I have a file which looks like this:

```
acc abcd etc. etc.
// line 1
// line 2
acc more words
// 3-4 more lines
acc some other words
```

There are some lines starting with `acc` and some that doesn't. I want to merge lines not starting with `acc` with those starting with it and still be separated by `@@`, so that my file has only lines starting with `acc` after the operation:

```
acc abcd etc. etc.@@//line 1@@//line 2
acc more words@@//3-4 more lines
acc some other words
```

I tried below command using global to segregate each set of lines and replace `\n` with `@@`:

```
:%g/^acc.*\_.\{-}\(^acc\)\@=/s/\n/@@/g
```

But I'm able to get only the first `\n` replaced by `@@` inside each pattern match of `:g`.

What am I doing wrong in this command?
Is there an easier way to do this?
Thanks.

Comment: `\(^acc\)` does not seem like it would match a start of line followed by `acc`. I think you need to use `\(\_^acc\)` instead, see `:help ordinary-atom`.

Comment: but that didn't seem to change anything... Nevermind.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather do it in several simple and intuitive steps than do it in a single complicated and hard-to-reason-about step. It seems like a more efficient approach to that kind of problem.

For example:

```
:v/^acc/s/^/@@
:%s/\n^@@/@@/
```

Explanation:

- prepend each line not starting with `acc` with `@@`,
- substitute every newline followed by `@@` with `@@`, effectively joining all the `@@` lines together *and* with the `acc` lines.

Comment: Thanks, your solution works. But out of curiosity, is there a way to make :g to work on multiple lines because the pattern matched is across many lines. I understand that my solution didn't work because search-replace was executed only on the lines where the pattern started, and not on the subsequent lines which were also part of the pattern being matched by :g.

Comment: `:global` works like this: 1st, it marks the matching lines in the given range, 2nd, it executes the given command on each marked line. Whether your pattern matches 1 or more lines, only the first line of the match is marked and the given command will be executed on that address.